# Create table from text list in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to bulk create a load of columns in a MySQL table?

I've got around 50 columns to create and it is taking a while to go through the phpMyAdmin interface.

I have the column names listed out in a text document and wondering if there is a way to load that up and tell it to add the empty columns to my existing table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible. You can convert list of names to SQL command for add columns.

For example you have list of columns

```
field1
field2
```

You should convert it to text

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN field1 VARCHAR(16);
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN field1 VARCHAR(16);
```

And then run this command in phpMyAdmin

You can make this command list by hand in your text editor or use Find/Replace function for automation this process.

I saw cases when peoples used Excel for this. Just import list of fields and add some text to prev column and some text in next column for each row. Then export to text and make small fix in needed.

Note: There type VARCHAR(16) is for example. You should use correct data type. You can see it in phpMyAdmin when you add column - it show SQL command that executed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.